# true copy vs object reference java

Tags: java, object, reference, deep-copy

I am in my second semester of school and I'm a little rusty on coding. I need to modify the `MyRectangle` large method such that when I run the program it prints out `30, 40, 50` instead of `50, 40, 50`.

I need to make a true copy rather than referencing the object. If I'm not mistaken I need to make a deep copy?

```
public class Tester
{
  public static MyRectangle large(MyRectangle first, MyRectangle second)
  {

    if(first.area() > second.area())
    {

        return first ;
    } 
    else
    {

        return second ;
    }        
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    MyRectangle r = new MyRectangle();
    r.setLength(30);
    r.setWidth(30);
    MyRectangle r2 = new MyRectangle();
    r2.setLength(40);
    r2.setWidth(20);   
    MyRectangle biggest = large(r, r2);
    biggest.setLength(50);
    System.out.println(r.getLength());
    System.out.println(r2.getLength());
    System.out.println(biggest.getLength());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please supply the code for `MyRectangle`. A deepClone may be required, but this is dependent on the object you want to copy and whet you intend to do with the object you copied from.

Comment: I solved the problem. I was just going about it the wrong way. I needed to just create two new MyRectangle objects:

Comment: MyRectangle newFirst = new MyRectangle() ;
        MyRectangle newSecond = new MyRectangle() ;

Comment: Thank you for the reply however.